# OSX services and contextual menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, contextmenu, finder

Can I use services to add items to the Finder context menu ?

Comment: What is has to do with superuser.com? Purely programming question about OS X services IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should look at [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).