# How to register a right-click menu for selected text in the OSX?

Tags: macos, electron

I want to add an OSX [Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(software)) app-like menu feature that registers an action which is made available OS-wide via the right-click menu, e.g.

[image: right-click menu]

Similar to the Dictionary, the menu feature that I want would need to be available everywhere in the OS and needs to appear only when there is text selected.

Answer (score 3):

In the Mac Developer Library: [Services Implementation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1).

Also maybe of interest:

- [Provide an OS X Service Without Launching the App?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27417916/38108)
- [OS X services and contextual menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7206241/38108)
- [Abracode Shortcuts](http://www.abracode.com/free/cmworkshop/shortcuts.html) – I have not used the product recently but if I recall correctly, some of what was *associated with* Shortcuts did not require nesting in the Services sub-menu.

---

Please note that **some applications may not behave as you require**.

For example, I can not get Firefox 44.0 on OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks to present *Services* in a contextual menu; no *Look Up* for integration with Dictionary; and so on –

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104331 was opened in 2001
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135268 was opened in 2002, resolved in 2008
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1133368 was treated as a duplicate of 104331 but I suspect that 1133368 is more like a duplicate of 135268

– it seems to me that the 2008 resolution is no longer effective.